# Extract all text from a certain xml tag using lxml

Tags: python, lxml

So I am looking to use lxml and python to grab all text from a tree that looks like this:

```
<Body>
  <X1>
    <Text>some text</Text>
    <Other>text I don't want</Other>
  </X1>
  <X2>
    <Text>some text</Text>
    <Other>text I don't want</Other>
  </X2>
```

The challenge here is that I want only the text that exist in the Text tag, but not the text that exists in other tags like Other. I need a way to iterate over all of the nodes within Body, and then combine the text from the nodes. This line of code gets me very close to what I want, but also picks up the text from the Other tags. So I need a way to weed out just the text I want.

```
text = "".join([x for x in root.find('.//Body').itertext()]).strip().replace('\n', '')
```

Again using the above tree and code the output is:
"some text text I don't want some text text I don't want"
Whereas I need:
"some text some text"

Thanks for all of the help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple xpath statement should do

```
>>> text="""<Body>
...   <X1>
...     <Text>some text</Text>
...     <Other>text I don't want</Other>
...   </X1>
...   <X2>
...     <Text>some text</Text>
...     <Other>text I don't want</Other>
...   </X2>
... </Body>"""
>>> 
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> doc = lxml.etree.fromstring(text)
>>> ' '.join(e.text for e in doc.xpath('//Text'))
'some text some text'
```

Comment: This didn't quite work for me, but it set me on the right path, thanks! I ended up using the following: `for body in root.find('.//Body'): for text_element in body.findall('.//Text'): print(etree.tostring(text_element, method='text', encoding=str))`